# unable to calculate a mean excluding current observation in a .each block in sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, each, mean

I have the following method.  My code snags at the `if statement` within my `.each` block with error: `nil can't be coerced into Float (TypeError)`.

I have tried **many** variants, all snag in `.each` block.

The code should calculate an average of **all** items, grouped by `Type`, **excluding the current observation**.  For example, 10 items with 10 different values under `Type foo`.  Item 1 has a cell calculating the mean of 9 items - **excluding** itself.  Please advise. I am at wit's end.

Code below is the method as existing in my IDE.  `Ruby 2.3.7`

`specific_row[0]` should pertain to `Id` and
`specific_row[1]` should pertain to `Amount`.
**Note:** I have made the choice to use `.execute` over `.execute2` in the effort not trip of the header data.

```
def billavgx(info_hash)
    begin
        db = SQLite3::Database.open('billinfo.db')
        db.results_as_hash = true
        db.transaction
        specific_amt =  db.prepare "SELECT Amount AND Id FROM bills WHERE Type = :Type" 
        specific_amt.execute info_hash[:category]
        specific_amt.each do |specific_row|
            if @total_rows == 1
                @avgx = (@total_amt - specific_row[1]) / @total_rows
            elsif @total_rows > 1
                @avgx = (@total_amt - specific_row[1]) / (@total_rows - 1)
            else
                return "insufficient entries"
            end         
            db.execute2 "UPDATE bills SET AvgX = :AvgX WHERE Id = :Id AND Type = :Type", @avgx, specific_row[0], info_hash[:category]
            end
        puts db.changes.to_s + " changes made"
        db.commit
    rescue SQLite3::Exception => e
        puts "error here " , e
    ensure
        specific_amt.close if specific_amt
        db.close if db
    end
end
```

Comment: Your first problem is that your query is not valid SQL. It should be `SELECT Amount, Id FROM bills...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem with the above `.each` block is the use of an `instance variable`.  Swapping `@avgx` for `local variable avgx` solves this problem. `avgx` can then be used in the SQL `UPDATE` statement.

Second `specific_row array` needs to specify the correct value.  In this case the  desired value is `Amount`.  Because `arrays` are 0-indexed, the value for `Amount` is stored in `specific_row[0]'.

```
        specific_amt.each do |specific_row|
            if @total_rows == 1
                avgx = @total_amt / @total_rows
            elsif @total_rows > 1
                avgx = (@total_amt - specific_row[0]) / (@total_rows - 1)
            else
                puts "insufficient entries"
                return "insufficient entries"
            end 
        db.execute2 "UPDATE bills SET AvgX = :AvgX WHERE Amount = :Amount AND Type = :Type AND Year = :Year", avgx, specific_row[0], info_hash[:category], info_hash[:year]
        end
```